# Manually setting object's position or have the object do it all?

Tags: actionscript-3, oop

I'm stuck thinking about the best way to go about setting a line segment's position, I have a class Line(length, angle, previous) being called from a class Polygon.. Right now I have:

```
public class Line extends Sprite {
    public function Line(length:Number, angle:Number, previous:Line = null) {
        if (previous != null) {
            this.x = previous.end.x;
            this.y = previous.end.y;
        } else {
            this.x = 0;
            this.y = 0;
        }
        /**/
    }
}
```

Now, is this the best practice or should I be doing:

```
Polygon.addLine(length:Number, angle:Number):void {
    var previous = (_line.length == 0) ? null : _line[_line.length - 1]; // Array containing all Lines
    var line:Line = new Line(length, angle, previous);
    line.x = (_line.length == 0) ? 0 : previous.end.x;
    line.y = (_line.length == 0) ? 0 : previous.end.y;
    /**/
}
```

One thing to add, Line is only used by Polygon in this application.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit: Completely rewrote my answer based on your comments...

Ok, so you always have a `Line` class and the question is where to put the logic to add a line to a polygon.

Your `Line` CTor assumes that there is an optional predecessor `Line` object. If you change that so the CTor takes an optional `Point`, there will be less coupling. Other classes, that might come in the future, can also construct lines using a starting point, length and angle. So the CTor approach looks good from that perspective.

Also, a polygon is basically a bunch of connected lines (and arcs as your comment suggests) so the logic for calculating the end point of a line seems to really belong into the `Line` class. Again, this way possible other users of `Line` won't have to duplicate `Polygon`'s code.

As already mentioned, there is a third way:
You can for example create a `LineFactory` class that creates a `Line` object based on start point, length and angle. That factory function would then do the calculation and set the start and in the end set end points of the line.

Comment: Each way there would be a Line class, I'm just wondering if it's better practice to have Line set it's own x,y based off Polygon's previous Line or if Polygon should do all the positioning itself.

Comment: Going off you're revision, I went that way starting out with.. But I ran into an issue with objects that are being set based off the individual Lines inside Polygon. Line has a .angle, .length, and .end property.

If I add an Arc object over the Polygon at say then endpoint of Line[2], the arc start angle would be Line[1].angle and the stop angle would be Line[3].angle

And Line.angle is based off the previous Line.angle, not off a central x,y